# Normal calculation for Splines

Tags: math, vector

I would like to implement a revolve tool for 2d splines in 3d. The geometry computation already works but the normals are a bit tricky. 
The problem is the angle between 2 points like the following image:
[image]

Here P1 is the previous point P2 the current point and P3 the next point.
How would I calculate the vector N.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for the inverse angle bisector?

```
dir1 = normalize(p1 - p2)
dir2 = normalize(p3 - p2)
n = normalize(-dir1 - dir2)
```